# How do I authenticate against Active Directory using php and CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, active-directory

I have code that authenticates against Active Directory using LDAP and boilerplate PHP code. However, I'm left wondering is there a more standard way to do this from within the CodeIgniter? Is there some plugin out there that makes this easier? So far, Google has failed me.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of interest but was removed for licencing issues:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/97004/

Here is an LDAP CI Library

http://github.com/dhorrigan/codeigniter-adldap